# ¿como hallo los numeros menores del promedio de los numeros de un array?

Tags: java, array

lo hice así pero me sale un error no se por que.
primero e hallado el promedio y despues queria hallar cuales son los numeros menores al promedio de los numeros que se encuentran en el array.
No se si me explico bien?

```js
public void mostrar()
    {
        double valorPromedio = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < numero.length; x++) {

            
            valorPromedio += numero[x];
            double Prom = valorPromedio/numero.length;
        
      String mayor="";
      for(int f=0; f<=numero.length; f++){
         if(numero[f]<Prom){
            mayor=mayor+" "+String.valueOf(numero[f]);
         }
      }
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"el menor numero es" +mayor);
      }
        
    }
```

ESTE ES EL PRINCIO DE MI CODIGO NO SE SI AYUDARA PERO POR SI LAS DUDAS LO DEJO AQUÍ,GRACIAS.

```js
public class ejercicios4 {
    int numero[];
    public static ejercicios4 objProgInter;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       objProgInter= new ejercicios4();
     objProgInter.Menup();
        
    }
    public ejercicios4()
    {
        numero = new int[10]; 
    }
    public void ingresar()
    {
       int n;
    for(int i=0;i<numero.length;i++)  {
        
    
        n=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese numeros:"));  
                numero[i]=n; 
            
    }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Qué error te da?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
 at pkg23ejercicios.ejercicios4.mostrar(ejercicios4.java:65)
 at pkg23ejercicios.ejercicios4.Menup(ejercicios4.java:88)
 at pkg23ejercicios.ejercicios4.main(ejercicios4.java:13)

Comment: public class ejercicios4 {
    int numero[];
    public static ejercicios4 objProgInter;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       objProgInter= new ejercicios4();
     objProgInter.Menup();
        
    }
    public ejercicios4()
    {
        numero = new int[10]; 
    }
    public void ingresar()
    {
       int n;
    for(int i=0;i<numero.length;i++)  {
        
    
        n=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese numeros:"));  
                numero[i]=n; 
            
    }
    }
     Bueno este es el pincipio de mi codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double promedio = 0;
int total = numeros.length;
int suma = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < total; i++)
{
   suma += numeros[i];
}

promedio = suma / total;

for(int i = 0; i < total; i++)
{
   if(numeros[i] < promedio)
   {
      //Imprimes que numeros[i] es menor que el promedio
   }
}
```

Declaras **3 variables**, una para almacenar el promedio, otra para guardar la cantidad de elementos que tiene el arreglo y otra para almacenar la suma de todos los elementos del arreglo.

Posteriormente hacemos un **ciclo for** que va a sumar todos los elementos del arreglo.

Después de finalizar este ciclo hallamos el promedio y posteriormente hacemos otro **ciclo for** donde iremos preguntando si el elemento del arreglo es menor que el promedio, de serlo se imprime que ese elemento del arreglo es menor que el promedio.